# Second Isomorphism Theorem Ambiguity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

We know the isomorphism theorem states that
for a Group G and subgroup H and normal subgroup N of it, We have :
$H/H$ $\cap$ $N \cong HN/N$
There is a Ambiguity for me that in the proof of this statement we use
map $\phi : H \to HN/N$ with $h\to hN$ and using first isomorphism theorem to get the statement. but with this reasoning we can also use $H/N$ instead of $HN/N$.

However why we can't say $H/N$ is just $HN/N$?

Comment: $H/N$ is not the same thing as $HN/N$.

Comment: why, please explain.

Comment: $HN/N$ is the same thing as $H/N$ when $N \subseteq H$, but in general this is not in the hypothesis of the theorem

Comment: "$H/N$" only makes sense when $N$ is contained in $H$, and the theorem makes no such assumption. $HN$ is the smallest subgroup that contains both $H$ and $N$, sonit is the smallest subgroup containing $H$ for which the quotient makes sense.

Comment: Let me add to the previous comments that I believe it to be a *convention* to write $H/N$ when $N$ is a normal subgroup of the group $H$. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of the group $G$, and $H \le G$, we might write (my temporary notation) $H//N = \{ h N : h \in H \}$, and this would be a subgroup of $G/N$  even if $N$ is not contained in $H$. However, we would lose uniqueness, it might well be that $H//N = K//N$ for some $H \ne K$. If we insist on $N \le H, K$ instead, then $H/N = K/N$ iff $H = K$, which is part of the third isomorphism theorem (aka the correspondence theorem).

Comment: Thanks you so much I understand.