# Notation $NM/M$ in the second isomorphism theorem

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I've been solving the following problems from Herstein:
" Given $N$ and $M$ normal in a group $G$, show that $NM/M$ is isomorphic to $N/N∩M$."

The problem is not difficult, but my doubt concerns the notation $NM/M$.
Now I know that $G/N=(gN)$, where N is normal in G. But in $NM/M$ I would have $(nmM)=(nM)=N/M$. So Herstein wrote it like that as a subtle hint (in my proof I've constructed a homomorphism from $NM$ to $N/N∩M$ with kernel $M$) or am I wrong?

Comment: You seem (twice) to be confusing a quotient group with one of its elements, i.e. with a coset. "Now I know that G/N=(gN)": no, G/N is a group whose elements are the gN's when g varies in G. "I would have (nmM)=(nM)=N/M": no, nM is not N/M. Moreover in this second case N/M makes no sense since M is not a subgroup of N.

Comment: Herstein did not write NM/M "as a subtle hint" but because M is a sugroup of NM and not of N.

Comment: [Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555246) (but which was only answered by comments).

Comment: Side remark: you don't need N to be normal.

Comment: I think I abused the notation, thanks a lot for the remark. One last thing just to make sure: the group NM/M is thus {nM with n varying in N}?

Comment: Yes your 2nd equality in (nmM)=(nM)=N/M was wrong but the 1st one was correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot you've been of great help

Comment: I would add that $N/M$ doesn't make sense unless $M$ is a subgroup of $N$. This is the purpose of the $NM$ notation.